# Angular + .Net Core 2.0 app: CSS and JSs imports

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, angular

As I started my app, I had been looking for a beautiful multi-select menu and found [this](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/).after installing it from its npm command, I included its CSS file in Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml. For bootstrap-select.js, the menu would not work if I import it in my component. So I imported the whole thing

```
import 'bootstrap-select';
```

in bootbrowser.ts file and it works just perfectly.

I'm planing to use other such beautiful plugins for my app but I'm concerned about whether if that is the best practice to import and include these files when you only are going to use them in one or two components. And will my app be slow when loading all the CSSs and JSs?

And I have been wondering is there a good reason to avoid using jQuery alongside bootstrap and angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's generally preferable not to include jquery in your application. It's sort of mixing frameworks and I think Angular prefers you to not directly hit the DOM yourself with things like JQuery. They have a change detection system that might not be in sync with stuff JQuery plugins might be doing.

I think size is always something to consider when building your app. Hopefully you can look into lazy loading. Then these javascript and css files will only be loaded when you enter those parts of the website. This is something to consider regardless if you are using Jquery plugins or writing your own code.

I recommend you look into an Angular third party library. I've used[NgPrime](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/multiselect) a little bit. They have a nice selection of stuff including a multiselect. They are also built in Angular so including them is just including an angular component. You can use it in you Angular templates with tags:

```
<p-multiSelect [options]="cities" [(ngModel)]="selectedCities"></p-multiSelect>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: NgPrime seems to be promising! Thank you! 

The installation steps are confusing when I install through the NPM command. Do I need to include the CSS and JS files to my components if it's already there in the node_modules folder?

Comment: Their documentation is a little bit confusing. I think they are talking about two ways to do the same thing. Hopefully you used the Angular cli to create your project and it should be easy to add NgPrime to your vendor bundles. Their documentation here https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/setup has a section called "Angular CLI Integration." I would follow that. Add font-awesome and ngprime to the dependencies. And pick the css style you like and add that to your styles section. Both should be in your angular-cli.json file. Then you can just import ngprime stuff in any of your angular files!